# FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] on os.getcwd()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm getting a FileNotFoundError on `os.getcwd()`

```
def setUp(self):
    try:
        self.previous_dir=os.getcwd()
    except:
        print("no file?")
    try:
        self.test_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        os.chdir(self.test_dir)
        self.logger.debug(f'CDed to {self.test_dir}')
    except (IOError, TypeError) as ioe:
        self.logger.error(f'Unable to make or CD to {self.test_dir}')                
        sys.exit(1)
```

I do a cd back to `self.previous_dir` in tearDown() and remove the temporary directory.

Is it trying to access the deleted file?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but I think it's clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was that `os.chdir()` had been set to the deleted directory by accident.  The directory was missing, but the error happened (it seems) at the attempt to get it with `os.getcwd()`.

I debugged it with `subprocess.run(['pwd'])`